# Is there a way to change ownership of a whole Linux directory and subfiles with chown in Python?

Tags: python, linux

Is there a way to change ownership of a whole Linux directory and subfiles with chown in Python?

I'm trying `os.chown(path, uid, gid)` but it doesn't change the permissions of all the subfiles and sub folders.

Comment: Walk the directory, and change the permissions of each file?